# AADSTS9002331: Application is configured for use by Microsoft Account users only. Please use the /consumers endpoint to serve this request

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-ad-b2c

So I registered an app for Personal account only. Then, I generated a sample blazor project with Visual Studio and set up the redirect url `https://localhost:7213/signin-oidc`. When I start the projects, it correctly redirects me to the `/signin-oidc` endpoint and following exception page is presented

> OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'invalid_request', error_description: 'AADSTS9002331: Application ... is configured for use by Microsoft Account users only. Please use the /consumers endpoint to serve this request.

Can't find anything in the docs about the consumers endpoint.

Tried changing `/singin-oidc` to `/consumers` but it didn't help.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you type the error code correctly?  The error number is not shown on Microsoft webpage : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-aadsts-error-codes

Comment: It think error should be AADSTS9002332 :  See https://thedatafarm.com/azure/azureaad/

Comment: It's definitely AADSTS9002331 https://imgur.com/a/l7W74wb

Comment: The `common` endpoint is for the Azure AD sign-in URL. Please check the Azure AD section of the application configuration and the endpoint there should be something like `https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers`.

Comment: My search engine switched from google to bing.  Bing is garbage.  Using google I found : https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/issues/194

Comment: @GauravMantri Tried it and the URL it produces ´https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/<client-id>/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration´ returns a 404 and the url without the consumers part actually delievers the configuration

Answer (score 9):

Solution:

Set 'tenantId' to consumers.

Code:

```
tenantId = consumers
```

Comment: This worked for me. But what is the difference? My application has a tenant-id, so what is the difference in giving a tenant-id value and just giving 'consumer'?

Comment: This also worked for me. Is there a link to the doc? MS has always been bad with their docs.

Answer (score 2):

> 'AADSTS9002331: Application ... is configured for use by Microsoft Account users only

You need to select  either the Second or Third option

[image]

You can also see same issue in MS Q& A by [AngangGuo](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-go/issues/50#issuecomment-1047478618)

***References taken from :***

[Register an application - Microsoft Advertising API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/guides/authentication-oauth-register?view=bingads-13)